# What is a proper way to manipulate DOM elements outside of Provider component in React + Redux.js app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am creating a React + Redux prototype app and I am facing a situation where I would like to manipulate the DOM outside the Provider component.

I have a root component in my React + Redux app:

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Main />
        </Provider>
        <DebugPanel top right bottom>
          <DevTools store={store} monitor={LogMonitor} />
        </DebugPanel>
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

I have a button inside Main which I would like to use for hiding the DebugPanel. For that reason I would like to manipulate the DebugPanel component class, or any element above it.

This leads me to following questions:

- How would I manipulate DebugPanel className?
- How do I manipulate DOM elements outside the Provider component, in example body or html tags?
- Can the store state changes be listened only inside Provider, or have I misunderstood?
- All this could be solved with little bit of jQuery. I could put that in to the store, but would that be a valid solution?
- What would be a "pure Redux" approach?

If you want to take a look of the code, it can be found on my git: 
https://github.com/JaakkoKarhu/redux-react-blockgenerator

Sorry if the code is a bit messy, I might be pushing there a lot of nonsense at the moment.

I hope this question is not too broad, I am looking for a 'best practices' type of approach here.

EDIT:

Edited the whole question to describe better what confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

First off: it looks like your code is your React.render() function.
Best practice is to call this function only once, to mount your react code. So first: change your initial render to:

```
React.render(
  <Main/>,
  document.getElementById('main')
);
```

And put all the other stuff in a full react  component.

As to your real question:
**The direct way to do it:**

- Put the classname in the root component's state.
- Add a function in root component which updates state.
- Pass this function as a prop to your  component.

When button is clicked in App component, root state changes, and DevTools will be re-rendered with new class.

Your root component code  would then include:

```
getInitialState() {
  return { devToolsClassName : 'dev-hidden' };
}

onClickInApp() {
  this.setState({ devToolsClassName : 'dev-visible' });
}
```

your render function inside main would look include the following changes:

```
...
      <App clickHandler={this.onClickInApp}/>
...
      <DevTools className={this.state.devToolsClassName} store={store} monitor={LogMonitor} />
```

Inside your  you would have a function (bound to the button click) like:

```
_onClick() {
  this.props.onClickInApp()
}
```

This would work, but the part where child calls a function inside parent is arguably an antipattern (though opinions on this vary).

So alternative: **Pure flux way to do it:**

- Put a `showDevTools` boolean in a store.
- Make your root component fetch it from store on each store change.
- Which would also trigger re-render.

Comment: Changed the initial render as adviced. However I don't fully understand your answer, probably because I noticed my question is also a bit unclear. I am looking for a "pure Redux" way to do this, if there is one.

Comment: I edited the whole question to describe better what bugs me. Sorry for the trouble if your answer does not apply anymore.

Comment: Your set of questions is still diverse, and not always quite clear: "outside Provider" includes both `<DebugPanel>` (is inside your App scope) and `<body>` (is outside your app scope). Big difference in best approach. But anyway,  I am not familiar with redux, so hopefully others can provide more helpful answers here.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Yes I still might be a bit confusing, the questions you refer to are actually the same thing